# Starting Pre-cache and pre-load apparmor profiles fails on boot

Tags: 14.10, apparmor

I found really few topics on the whole internet about this failure, so I couldn't debug or investigate much. During the boot process I started to see the error some months ago:

```
* Starting Pre-cache and pre-load apparmor profiles                     [fail]
```

I couldn't say if it started after a particular upgrade.
I'm on Ubuntu 14.10.

```
cat /var/log/upstart/apparmor.log

Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.mediascanner-service-2.0 in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.mediascanner-service-2.0 at line 14: Could not open '/usr/share/apparmor/hardware/audio.d'
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.mediascanner-service-2.0 in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.mediascanner-service-2.0 at line 14: Could not open '/usr/share/apparmor/hardware/audio.d'
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.mediascanner-service-2.0 in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.mediascanner-service-2.0 at line 14: Could not open '/usr/share/apparmor/hardware/audio.d'
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.mediascanner-service-2.0 in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.mediascanner-service-2.0 at line 14: Could not open '/usr/share/apparmor/hardware/audio.d'
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
```

Comment: Can you report anything relevant in the log file that corresponds to this error: `/var/log/upstart/apparmor.log`?

Comment: find it in the edit

Comment: purging the package has solved. Edit your answer and I will award the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in mediascanner2.0 and I have filed [bug 1443693](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mediascanner2/+bug/1443693) for you.

As a workaround, you can run:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/apparmor/hardware/{audio,graphics,video}.d
```

or alternatively **purge** the `mediascanner2.0` package if you don't need it (assuming that this is a desktop and not a phone).

Comment: I removed the package but the problem is not solved.

Answer (score -5):

Try downgrading to 14.04, that should work.

If you want 14.10, try backing up all your data and then doing a CLEAN INSTALL using a CD or a Flash Drive.

Comment: Do you have any reason to recommend a downgrade to 14.04?

Comment: It is more stable...  Also, that is no reason to downvote it.

Comment: IMO, suggesting drastic actions such as downgrading or doing a clean install does not exactly constitute a constructive answer. It may technically solve the problem, but that is analogous to recommending someone to rebuild their house without a good reason (say, "the new house will have less problems") when they're asking about peeling paint on the walls and how to best fix it.

Comment: Okay............ :( sorry. I'm just trying to help.

Comment: Look at my profile. Do you think I would ever ask a question if the solution is downgrade?